# Image/Icon changes location on page scroll (unwanted)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, alignment

Bit of a frustrating one I've been trying to wrap my head around for the past few days. I'm using a WordPress Theme, and within that, I've got an image gallery that automatically slides through a series of photographs, with a title, and small icon displayed on each image 'slide'.

I've aligned the images to sit above the text, using the following kind of snippets for each slide icon:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 55vh;
right: 30vw!important;
```

Here's the CSS for the text:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 10vh;
left: 10vw !important;
```

And additionally, here's a link to the staging page: https://cnaportal.com/cem-annual-report-test-level-1/#

The frustrating part is, when initially loading the page, the icons are sitting on top of the text, incorrectly aligned. It isn't until you slightly scroll down the page, and then scroll through the image gallery, that the icons are correctly displayed. For example, here's what one image looks like on initial page load:

[image]

And here is what it looks like if you scroll slightly:
[image]

Any advice on how to prevent/fix this would be really appreciated - i'm still wrapping my head around the basics, so really appreciate any advice!

Comment: can you share some more code that you have done? styles and HTML for the text and icon?

Comment: Sure thing - the code just sits in basic <h1> tags for the heading, but here's the CSS for it:  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
bottom: 10vh;
    left: 10vw !important;